# GeoLocator Not Working on IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, geolocation

Using James M.'s GeoLocator plugin for IOS in shared PCL project. While debugging, the app stalls on the GetLocation call. I noticed in the Output window the Xamarin.IOS.dll was 32 bit while everything else is 64 bit as follows:

> Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6D184802-675A-4761-B704-F73C3AF1FB05/HealthiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Core.dll
>
> Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6D184802-675A-4761-B704-F73C3AF1FB05/HealthiOS.app/.monotouch-32/Xamarin.iOS.dll
>
> Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6D184802-675A-4761-B704-F73C3AF1FB05/HealthiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Xml.dll

Not sure if this is contributing to the issue, however, I am using the Connectivity plugin and Settings Plugins without issue. The following is the call I am making to the GeoLocator object.

```
var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
// locator.AllowsBackgroundUpdates = true;
locator.DesiredAccuracy = 500;
var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 7000);
return position;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you read the IMPORTANT section in the Readme?  https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin

Comment: Jason. Thanks for your suggestion but yes I did. I am running IOS 9.3.5 on an ipad. Tried each and both of the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription, NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription settings.

Comment: @Jason. Thanks for your help. I am using the plist settings. I went into the logs and saw a message regarding the Xamarin.IOS versions between visual studio (9.6.1.8) and the mac (10.0.1) but not sure how to bring visual studio up to version 10. Also saw this message in the Xamarin logs on my windows computer: SshOperationTimeoutException: Connection failed to establish within 10000 milliseconds